# flatMapFirst: flatMap which adds new observable only if the previous one ended

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

How to implement `flatMapFirst` operator which is like `flatMap`, but adds new observable only if the previous one ended? If the previous one still running, it just ignores the new observable. How to implement it in RxJava 2?

It already exists in bacon - [flatMapFirst](https://baconjs.github.io/api.html#observable-flatmapfirst)
And in kefir - [flatMapFirst](https://rpominov.github.io/kefir/#flat-map-first).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it with this:

````
/**
 * Flatmaps upstream items into [source] items.
 * Ignores upstream items if there is any [source] instance currently running.
 *
 * ```
 * upstream ----u-----u---u-------u---------------|-->
 *              ↓                 ↓               ↓
 * source       ---s-------|->    ---s-------|->  ↓
 *                 ↓                 ↓            ↓
 * result   -------s-----------------s------------|-->
 * ```
 */
fun <T, R> Observable<T>.flatMapWithDrop(source: Observable<R>): Observable<R> {
  return this.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.DROP)
    .flatMap({ source.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.MISSING) }, 1)
    .toObservable()
}
````

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a new operator but a combination of existing ones:

```
source.onBackpressureLatest().flatMap(function, 1)
```

FlatMap will run 1 inner source at once and onBackpressureLatest will keep dropping outer source values (except the latest) if there is no demand while flatMap runs the 1 inner source.

If you don't want to continue with the latest available from source, consider using `onBackpressureDrop` instead.

Comment: It seems it works with onBackpressureDrop() instead of onBackpressureLatest(). Is onBackpressureDrop() is the correct one?

Comment: I'm going to correct that to onBackpressureDrop(), feel free to correct it back if it's a mistake

Comment: They have different semantic meaning: with `onBackpressureDrop` you may have a gap in processing if the source paused for some reason after a burst.

Comment: @akarnokd, seems like this works only with `Flowable`-s. Is there any short cut analogue of `flatMapFirst` for `Observable` without conversion to `Flowable`?

Comment: No, this is a backpressure effect cheaply available via `Flowable`. You'd have to write a custom `Observable` operator.

Answer (score 0):

A follow-up to [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41828956/2468555). If you're looking a way of having `flatMapFirst` in RxJava 2 `Observable`, not `Flowable`, here is a quick Kotlin implementation:

```
fun <T, R> Observable<T>.flatMapFirst(transform: (T) -> Observable<R>) =
    toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.DROP)
        .flatMap({ transform(it).toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER) }, 1)
        .toObservable()
```

**UPD.** Alternative implementation based on David Karnok's suggestion:

```
fun <T, R> Observable<T>.flatMapFirst(transform: (T) -> Observable<R>) =
    Observable.defer {
        val busy = AtomicBoolean()
        return@defer this
                .filter { busy.compareAndSet(false, true) }
                .flatMap {
                    transform(it).doAfterTerminate { busy.set(false) }
                }
    }
```

Comment: BackpressureStrategy.MISSING is the wrong strategy here. You need to apply an `onBackpressureXXX` operator otherwise flatMap will most likely overflow its inner queue.

Comment: @akarnokd, as I understood `.BUFFER` would be a reasonable equivalent to SpscLinkedArrayQueue's behavior under the hood of Observable.flatMap. Or I'm missing something?

Comment: That was the question, if it should be BUFFER in there or something else :) Edited.

Comment: This may lead to excess memory usage. You could just filter out upstream items until the inner source completes: `filter(v->atomicBoolean.compareAndSet(false, true))` and `flatMap(v -> obs.doAfterTerminate(() -> atomicBoolean.set(false))`.